# Switch id numbers of two rows in MySql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am trying to switch the id's of two rows in mysql using php - the more i read about it the more confused i get. There seems to be a lot of conflicting information. Has anybody got a definitive answer.

eg in initial state my rows are

```
1-Peter-22-germany
2-mary-16-iceland
3-tom-29-france
4-michael-34-greece
```

and then i would like to swap the id's of rows 2 and 3 so that it would look like this

```
1-Peter-22-germany
3-mary-16-iceland
2-tom-29-france
4-michael-34-greece
```

so that if i then ordered it by id i would have

```
1-Peter-22-germany
2-tom-29-france
3-mary-16-iceland
4-michael-34-greece
```

Comment: @amosrivera thanks i was just trying to do that - sorry

Comment: Do you actually want to change the ID or just get it in a different order sometimes?

Comment: @byronyasgur no prob, just select the text and press ctrl + k that will give it code format

Comment: no as i was saying i need to regularly change the order permanently

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**If the ID is the primary key then you don't want to change it/be able to change it.** If this is only for sorting, I would suggest making an "order" column that is an integer and sorting on that. Table schema would be nice to see for this but this is my recommendation so far.

If ID is created automatically when rows are entered then this idea is an even larger problem. However, now I'm just speculating as I don't know your table schema.

Here is some standard advice on primary keys: **Do not think of them as anything except a unique identifier.**

Comment: i have a list that i want to change the order of individual elements  - it's not for sorting - i want to be able to manipulate the table and have the changes permanent

Comment: What is the reasoning behind wanting to change the IDs? I don't think I understand why you want to accomplish this.

Comment: i wanting to change order in which the table displays permanently .... like if it was set to ORDER BY date and i changed one of the dates .... except it's by ID .... i guess i could have another column which would contain the sort order and change that instead of ID

Comment: @byronasgur If you're wanting to change the order *at all*, then it's sorting.  Brian's suggestion of an order column will accomplish this.  Any time you want to change the order, just change the values within the order column.  When you display the list, you will sort it first by new column.

Comment: what would be the benefit of having another column though ?

Comment: The safest way to do it is to create a new colum with the sort order. Trust me when I say this but you do not want to get in the habit of adjusting primary keys. Depending on how you view your database you could create the "Sort" column, then create a view that sorts by that column but doesn't display the sort column. Try to think of the ID (primary key) as only a unique identifier and not as an order.

Comment: @byronyasgur "what would be the benefit of having another column though ?" The benefit is that you can safely sort on it. You don't want to change PKs because if you do it wrong you can lose data. And by lose data I mean gone forever. The benefit is peace of mind :) Plus, unless you're on a SUPER terrible server there's no reason it can't handle another column.

Comment: understood but what code would i use to swap to row's "sortorder" values ..... would i need to use a temporary variable

Comment: Yes, you can use a temp variable, $temp = $item1; $item1 = $item2; $item2 = $temp; Then run the SQL UPDATE (twice) with the new variables.

Comment: @byronyasgur Look at Marc B's answer with the UPDATE statement for a single-query way of doing the swap.  Obviously you'd change the id column to the new column you're adding.

Answer (score 14):

```
UPDATE yourtable SET id=IF(id=2, 3, 2) where id in(2,3)
```

might do the trick, but this is a bad idea - manipulating/reassigning primary key values is never a good idea.

If this fails, then it's because of a duplicate key violation (most likely), and you'd need to temporarily reassign one of the IDs to something completely other unique value so you don't get a conflict while the reassignment is in progress - this would require you to use two queries at least.

Comment: manipulating/reassigning primary key values is never a good idea. - ultimately it's a list ( like a tasks list/shopping list etc) and i need to be able to change the list order ( not just order it alphabetically or anything like that like using ORDERBY .... i need to be able to regularly change the order of it ) .... what would you advise

Comment: Add a second integer field that you can use for sorting on, instead. There'd be no harm in changing that field as much as you want. Primary keys should be left alone once assigned. Especially when using them for foreign keys.

Comment: unfortunately this fails with `Duplicate entry '2' for key 'PRIMARY'`

Answer (score 1):

I am dying to know why you need it to be permanent. The only things I can think of are so you can alter the apparent sequence of events.

as others stated, IDs are typically primary keys and auto-numbered, so that makes it difficult, but the obvious way to achieve this is to gather all field data from the two items into an array, and UPDATE each record with the VALUES from the other one.

Comment: thanks - i think i was asking about changing id when really i should have had another column "sortorder" and changing that .... if i had a list bread milk fish and i wanted to change it to bread fish milk and leave it that way....so that every time i sorted by that column ( eg sortorder ) it would show up as the way it was last left .... thats the basis of it i just want to be able to reorder a list

Comment: yeah, the separate column is the way to go. I thought I saw you comment that that was not what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `SORT BY` something. We need to see your table schema.

Comment: no as i answered below i dont just want to sort the table differently - i want to change it permanently

Comment: @byronyasgur: Tables don't have an an inherent order until you sort them. The rows could come out of the query in any order.

Comment: @duskwuff "Tables don't have an an inherent order until you sort them." I like that, it's very true and to the point.

Answer (score 0):

Swap IDs relatively easy to implement with stored procedure and tempopary table:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `swapIDs`(aTable varchar(64),aID1 int(11),aID2 int(11))
BEGIN
 drop temporary table if exists swapIDsTable;
 SET @s = concat('create temporary table swapIDsTable like ',aTable); PREPARE stmt FROM @s; EXECUTE stmt; DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
 SET @s = concat('insert into swapIDsTable select * from ',aTable,' where id=',aID1);  PREPARE stmt FROM @s; EXECUTE stmt; DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
 SET @s = concat('delete from ', aTable, ' where id=',aID1); PREPARE stmt FROM @s; EXECUTE stmt; DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
 SET @s = concat('update ', aTable, ' set id=',aID1,' where id=',aID2); PREPARE stmt FROM @s; EXECUTE stmt; DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
 SET @s = concat('update swapIDsTable set id=',aID2,' where id=',aID1); PREPARE stmt FROM @s; EXECUTE stmt; DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
 SET @s = concat('insert into ', aTable,' select * from swapIDsTable where id=',aID2); PREPARE stmt FROM @s; EXECUTE stmt; DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
 drop temporary table if exists swapIDsTable;
END |
```

But imagine, you've swaped id's which is updating by another user on client (application) side and only clue (for application) to understand which raw to update is ID. That would be nightmare.

So this procedure can be 100% usefull in only single user usage.

Another way is to update (exchange) all columns values between two rows:

```
UPDATE targetTable tab1, targetTable tab2 SET tab1.<colX>=tab2.<colX>, tab2.<colX>=tab1.<colX>  where tab1.id=<id1> and tab2.id=<id2>;
```

There is still need to be some sync mechanism.

Comment: You suggest to delete one row and then re-insert it (with the different ID)? Since this is a Primary Key, won't that fail if there are Foreign Keys that reference it? Or succeed and delete (a million more) rows in other tables (if there are `CASCADE DELETE` actions defined)?

Comment: Yes, Foreign Keys and CASCADE DELETE would be problem in stored proc/temp table case. But i didn't saw that in initial question :)