# Mysql: How to swap data of one column between rows?

Tags: php, mysql

I already read [Switch id numbers of two rows in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6630121/switch-id-numbers-of-two-rows-in-mysql) and [Mysql: Swap data for different rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17433666/mysql-swap-data-for-different-rows), yet I don't understand. Suppose a table colors that looks like this:

```
------------------------------------------
| id | box | pouch  | color    | value   |
-----------------------------------------
| 1  |  1  |   1    | red      | 30      |
| 2  |  1  |   1    | blue     | 20      |
| 3  |  1  |   1    | green    | 10      |
| 4  |  1  |   1    | yellow   | 40      |
| 5  |  1  |   1    | purple   | 20      |
| 6  |  1  |   1    | black    | 50      |
| 7  |  1  |   2    | red      | 30      |
| 8  |  1  |   2    | blue     | 20      |
| 9  |  1  |   2    | green    | 10      |
| 10 |  1  |   2    | yellow   | 40      |
| 11 |  1  |   2    | purple   | 20      |
| 12 |  1  |   2    | black    | 50      |
| 13 |  2  |   1    | red      | 35      |
| 14 |  2  |   1    | blue     | 25      |
| 15 |  2  |   1    | green    | 15      |
| 16 |  2  |   1    | yellow   | 45      |
| 17 |  2  |   1    | purple   | 25      |
| 18 |  2  |   1    | black    | 55      |
| 19 |  2  |   2    | red      | 35      |
| 20 |  2  |   2    | blue     | 25      |
| 21 |  2  |   2    | green    | 15      |
| 22 |  2  |   2    | yellow   | 45      |
| 23 |  2  |   2    | purple   | 25      |
| 24 |  2  |   2    | black    | 55      |
------------------------------------------
```

How can I swap the "value" of a row with another, leaving the "id", "box", "pouch", and "color" intact?

Notes:
 1. I need to swap the value of box='1' with box='2'
 2. The number of rows are dynamic

Example:

```
SWAP ROWS OF VALUE WITH BOX='1' WITH ROWS OF VALUE WITH BOX='2'
```

Result:

```
------------------------------------------
| id | box | pouch  | color    | value   |
-----------------------------------------
| 1  |  1  |   1    | red      | 35      |
| 2  |  1  |   1    | blue     | 25      |
| 3  |  1  |   1    | green    | 15      |
| 4  |  1  |   1    | yellow   | 45      |
| 5  |  1  |   1    | purple   | 25      |
| 6  |  1  |   1    | black    | 55      |
| 7  |  1  |   2    | red      | 35      |
| 8  |  1  |   2    | blue     | 25      |
| 9  |  1  |   2    | green    | 15      |
| 10 |  1  |   2    | yellow   | 45      |
| 11 |  1  |   2    | purple   | 25      |
| 12 |  1  |   2    | black    | 55      |
| 13 |  2  |   1    | red      | 30      |
| 14 |  2  |   1    | blue     | 20      |
| 15 |  2  |   1    | green    | 10      |
| 16 |  2  |   1    | yellow   | 40      |
| 17 |  2  |   1    | purple   | 20      |
| 18 |  2  |   1    | black    | 50      |
| 19 |  2  |   2    | red      | 30      |
| 20 |  2  |   2    | blue     | 20      |
| 21 |  2  |   2    | green    | 10      |
| 22 |  2  |   2    | yellow   | 40      |
| 23 |  2  |   2    | purple   | 20      |
| 24 |  2  |   2    | black    | 50      |
------------------------------------------
```

Anyone got some ideas? Thanks

Comment: Does `box` have a foreign key constraint to another table? If so, I will add an extra note to my question.

Comment: @halfer no, it doesn't have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a table that holds all values you want to swap.

```
 create table tmp_t as select * from t;
```

Then update your table twice:

```
update t t1 
inner join tmp_t t2 on t1.color = t2.color 
                    and t1.pouch = t2.pouch 
                    and t1.box = 1 and t2.box = 2 
set t1.value = t2.value;

update t t1 
inner join tmp_t t2 on t1.color = t2.color 
                    and t1.pouch = t2.pouch 
                    and t1.box = 2 and t2.box = 1 
set t1.value = t2.value;
```

And that's it. See it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/75d688/1/0).

Comment: @tobalizard: once you have decided which answer was the most helpful, you can accept it by clicking on the tick mark to the left of the question. That's how we label questions as 'answered' on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

To do the swap, try resetting one of them to a temporary value. You need to do that, otherwise the second update will affect the first one.

```
UPDATE mytable SET box = -1 WHERE box = 1; -- Set box 1 to a temporary value
UPDATE mytable SET box = 1 WHERE box = 2; -- Set box 2 to box 1
UPDATE mytable SET box = 2 WHERE box = -1; -- Set box 1 to box 2
```

I've assumed it is not possible to have a negative box number. If `-1` is permissible, use something else, such as `null`.

For extra safety, wrap the above in a transaction, so if anything goes wrong, you can rollback.